# How to read part of a chunked stream

Tags: dart

In Dart, `stdin` is a `Stream<List<int>>`. Bytes come in in chunks. What I want is a function that reads from stdin until I get some character (say `'\0'`), and then returns, so that future readers of stdin get the data after the `'\0'`.

Unfortunately because of the chunking, the `'\0'` byte might be in the middle of a chunk, so I kind of want to read a chunk, remove part of it, and then push it back to the start of the stream. But there isn't any way to do this.

Another option would be `readByteSync()` but reading bytes one at a time is going to be slow and this is in a GUI program so I can't use sync methods.

Comment: I don't know if there's anything existing that does it, but could you wrap `stdin` in a custom class (possibly a type of `Stream`) that does allow you to push bytes back, and then use the wrapped version everywhere?

Comment: Yeah that's probably the best option I can think of at the moment - wrap it in `expandAsync()` and have a "pass through" flag. Sucks that its extra code that isn't doing anything for 99% of the stream's life though.

Answer (score 1):

I think actually because a `Stream<>` can only ever be listened to once - even if a previous listener cancels its subscription - the only way is to have something permanently filtering the stream's events until the end of time. So you may as well just split the stream into two streams:

```
import 'dart:async';

class StdioPreambleSplitter {
  StdioPreambleSplitter(this._input) {
    var preambleFinished = false;
    _input.listen((chunk) {
      if (preambleFinished) {
        _dataStream.add(chunk);
      } else {
        final nullByte = chunk.indexOf(0);
        if (nullByte == -1) {
          _dataStream.add(chunk);
        } else {
          preambleFinished = true;
          _preambleStream.add(chunk.sublist(0, nullByte));
          _dataStream.add(chunk.sublist(nullByte));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<List<int>> preambleStream() {
    return _preambleStream.stream;
  }

  Stream<List<int>> dataStream() {
    return _dataStream.stream;
  }

  final Stream<List<int>> _input;
  final StreamController<List<int>> _preambleStream = new StreamController();
  final StreamController<List<int>> _dataStream = new StreamController();
}
```

Hopefully it doesn't add too much overhead.